# how to get unique rows from array in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

i have a collection with some of duplicate objects , i want filter array and get unique collection
this is my array

```
array=[{id:1,name:'A'},{id:2,name:'B'},{id:3,name:'C'},{id:1,name:'A'},{id:3,name:'C'}];
```

i want to filter like below

```
array=[{id:1,name:'A'},{id:2,name:'B'},{id:3,name:'C'}];



  var unique = [];
    for(let i = 0; i< this.array.length; i++){    
        if(unique.indexOf(this.array[i].id) === -1){
            unique.push(this.array[i].id);        
        }        
    }
```

i tried above and am getting unique values but i want complete object

Answer (score 1):

You can do with arrray.filter as follows,

```js
var unique = {}
var array=[{"id":1,"name":'A'},{"id":"2","name":'B'},{"id":3,"name":'C'},{"id":1,"name":'A'},{"id":3,name:'C'}];
var arrFiltered = array.filter(obj => !unique[obj.id] && (unique[obj.id] = true));
console.log(arrFiltered)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with help of [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
let arr=[{id:1,name:'A'},{id:2,name:'B'},{id:3,name:'C'},{id:1,name:'A'},{id:3,name:'C'}];

let op = Object.values(arr.reduce((o,c)=>{
  if(!o[c.id]) o[c.id] = c;
  return o; }, {} ))

console.log(op);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are almost there.  Just add the object instead of the ID to the array, ie:

```
unique.push(this.array[i]);
```

That should do it if I understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

Replace Id with the respective key of the array.

```
arrayUnique(array)
{
    let result:any=[];
    let compare:any=[]; 
    array.forEach((val,ind)=>{
        if(!compare.includes(val.id))
        {
            compare.push(val.id);
            result.push(val);  
        }
    });
    console.log(result);  
}
```